# iPhone SDK: How to re-route iPhone audio through built in receiver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, ios5

So I have an application that is playing audio using an AVAudioPlayer. Everything works just fine, its just that I would like the audio to be re-routed to the iPhone's built in receiver at the top of the phone when the user puts it up to their ear.

I've shut the screen off with the proximity sensor when the user puts the phone up to their ear. I've searched and it seems like this ability is no possible in iOS 5 using kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver. However, I'm note sure how to implement it.

My current code:

```
- (void)sensorStateChange:(NSNotificationCenter *)notification
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] proximityState] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Device is close to user.");

        //I thought the below would change the audio route, but it doesn't work.

        SET_PROPERTY (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, UInt32, kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver); 
    }
    else  
    {
        NSLog(@"Device is NOT close to user.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `SET_PROPERTY`, is it a macro to do the following?

```
const CFStringRef audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
```

Also make sure proximity sensor is enabled, call at the app start (or more adequate place):

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I haven't declared it at all. I'm just wondering what the quickest way to implement it is.

Comment: I suggest the following reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: When I replace my code with yours I get an "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'SInt32' (aka 'long') with an expression of type 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const')" warning

Comment: I fixed the code, however this should be something you could figure out.

Comment: Also worth noting audio is already playing when that function is called.

Comment: I'm just new to AVFoundation. The code is also still not working, however I do appreciate your help. I've been researching this for quite a while.